# Problems with JGL R function for input list of more than 2 matrices

Tags: r, networking, sparse-matrix

I am working with the joint graphical lasso by the JGL R function and I discovered some incoherent results if we want to estimate the joint precision matrices for more than 2 classes, which I would like to discuss with someone who used this package.

I have 3 different classes, each one described by a matrix having as columns p variables (the same for all) and as rows the cases (different for every class). Giving as input the list of the 3 matrices, JGL returns a list of 3 sparse precision matrices, one for each class, with columns/rows corresponding to the variables which have at least one connection in at least one class.

If I apply JGL to a list of 2 classes, everything is fine, yet if I consider a list of 3, I obtain precision matrices with more variables than the one really connected. For instance, I obtain as output sparse precision matrices of dimension 93x93, but if I keep only the variables with links, I obtain a total of 83 variables (specifically, 60 for the first class, 29 for the second, and 70 for the third). I checked in the JGL output, and actually, the "extra" variables really have no connections, so there should be no errors in the way I extract the "submatrices" with only the connected nodes...

I thought it could be a computational issue of JGL. Has someone already had this kind of experience? Do you know what is happening?

Thank you in advance!